# Why does the datepicker add a calendar in my view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-calendar

I am starting to learn how to develop on Android. It is pretty straightforward but I'm facing an issue I did not find any mention anywhere...

I have a view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editNomProduit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/ht_nom_produit" />



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelQuantiteProduitEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/labelQuantiteProduitEdit"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editQuantite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerUnite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labeDateAchatProduitEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/labelDateAchatProduitEdit"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/dpDateAchatProduit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Which displayed a datepicker. The thing is that the date picker seems to add a Calendar besides the classic rollers for the date picker (see picture). I don't want this view, juste the roller for the date. Am I usign the date picker in the wrong way or is this the orignal behavior ?
 Thanks !

Guillaume

[image: Date picker with canlendar]

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Add this line to your date picker xml

```
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

This will remove the Calendar.

Comment: Indeed this helped a lot ! Thanks

Comment: It will work if you write ```android:datePickerMode="spinner" ```.

Comment: I just want to add that this option is available on for API 11 and above.

Comment: how do you do this programatically (when the picker is created using code and there is no XML?)  under API level >= 24?

Answer (score 6):

All you need add under the:

```
 <datepicker>
```

method, just add:

```
 android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

This will remove the calendar, but keep the scroller.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I haven't created any xml file. So I fixed by changing the value of `calendarviewshow` in Activity. Hope it will help somebody.

We can hide the calendar view in `DatePicker` using two methods.

1 In Layout(XML file)(Thanks to @coconess)

> ```
> <DatePicker
>     android:id="@+id/datepickerv1"
>     android:calendarViewShown="false">
> ```

2 In Activity(Java file)

```
Note: If you are not using "calendarViewShow" in xml, follow this step.
```

> ```
> DatePicker dp=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datepickerv1);
> dp.setCalendarViewShown(false);
> ```

Comment: setCalendarViewShown is deprecated in API version 24, now what?

Answer (score 1):

Change your datepicker from xml as follows :

```html
<DatePicker
android:id="@+id/dpDateAchatProduit"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```

instead of

```
android:calenderViewShown="false"
```