# Can I use a DatePicker without showing the calendar?

Tags: android, android-layout

DatePicker is taking up a lot of space. I just want to display the tabs for date, month and year and no calendar. Is it possible?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462448/how-to-turn-off-calendarview-in-a-datepicker and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670695/why-does-the-datepicker-add-a-calendar-in-my-view and probably others.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

Comment: just use this,dueDatePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);

Comment: minDateSelector.setCalendarViewShown(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting a later version of the API, you can use the following XML (no need to write Java code) in your

**android:calendarViewShown="false"**

The method in DatePicker

public void setCalendarViewShown (boolean shown);

e.g.  : dateselecter.setCalendarViewShown(false);